# Prevent Windows 10 Wifi hotspot turning off automatically on 1809

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, hotspot

Anyone found a solution for this Windows issue on the latest versions? 1709/1809 have the same issue.

Another user answered this issue but the fix only works in older Windows versions apparently:
[https://superuser.com/questions/1144664/windows-10-mobile-hotspot-turning-off-on-its-own#*=*](https://superuser.com/questions/1144664/windows-10-mobile-hotspot-turning-off-on-its-own#_=_)

Windows documentation is incomplete, and i've checked there is no policy controlling the wifi hotspot timeout:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/wcd/wcd-hotspot#wcd-policies.md#wifi

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I am looking for a workaround to this issue, since it's obvious it can't be prevented [Turn on mobile hotspot remotely via Bluetooth](https://superuser.com/questions/1517974/turn-on-windows-mobile-hotspot-remotely-via-bluetooth)

Comment: I didn't find a solution if i remember back then, and i don't need to use it now..i hope they've fixed it