# Turn on Windows Mobile hotspot remotely via Bluetooth

Tags: windows-10, reverse-tethering

I set up a WiFi Mobile hotspot on a HP notebook, which shares the internet from its Ethernet connection to my other Dell PC. Both run Windows 10.

I have failed to prevent the automatic hotspot shutdown after following several guides on the internet, and apparently, it's a common issue. *([Prevent Windows 10 Wifi hotspot turning off automatically on 1809](https://superuser.com/questions/1422743/prevent-windows-10-wifi-hotspot-turning-off-automatically-on-1809))*

Though, it seems to be possible to turn on the hotspot remotely *(see image#1)*, but I can't figure out how to do that from the Dell *(image#2)*, nor from my Samsung S9 (which I would accept as a workaround).

> So, the question is:
>
> **How do I turn on the hotspot remotely?**
>   *I would consider rewarding any **workaround** as well if it meant I don't have to unlock the HP and turn the hotspot on via its settings, though I will reserve the Accepted answer for the "**Turn on Remotely**" feature.*

---

*<sub>This is how the Mobile hotspot settings look. Notice **Turn on remotely** at the bottom.</sub>*
[image: Mobile hotspot settings showing Turn on remotely at the bottom.[2]]

It's only possible to Connect using Direct connection.
[image: Connect to HP using Direct connection]

Comment: So to be clear your ultimate goal is to keep the hotspot running? Does it matter if the connection were to disconnect for approx a minute before it comes back on? I think a powershell script to run every minute to check if the hotspot is on/off, if off to turn the hotspot on again? Would that suffice what you need?

Comment: @CraftyB Running a PS script every minute would be a valid workaround, nice one. Though, what do you mean by the connections being disconnected for a minute?

Comment: After looking @harrymc 's answer the last section of his answer that points to another answer is using the same libraries that I would have used and therefore would have duplicated content so please use that script. With regards to the connection dropping for upto a minute, if the schedule runs bang on the minute and the hotspot drops at 1 second passed the minute then the connection will be down for 59 seconds until the script is executed again.

Answer (score 1):

The following measures should help to keep the hotspot on:

- Ensure that the computer will not enter Sleep/Hibernate
- In *Settings >  Network & Internet > Mobile Hotspot*,
  toggle off "When no devices are connected, automatically turn off mobile hotspot".
- Disable Wifi adapter power management options
  in Device Manager, expand Network devices,
  right-click the Wifi adapter, Properties, Power Management tab, uncheck
  "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", click OK
- For the Mobile Hotspot not to turn off itself:

  - In the Services applet, stop the "Mobile Hotspot Service" (icssvc)
  - In `regedit`, navigate to
    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\icssvc\Settings`
  - Create a DWORD Key named `PeerlessTimeoutEnabled` with the value of `0`
  - Restart the Mobile Hotspot Service (icssvc)

  Alternatively, execute the following PowerShell command with admin privileges:

  ```
  powershell -windowstyle hidden -command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/s,/c,net stop "icssvc" & REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\icssvc\Settings" /V PeerlessTimeoutEnabled /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F & net start "icssvc"' -Verb runAs"
  ```

---

- If all else fails,
  [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1434648/8672)
  contains a PowerShell script to turn on the Mobile Hotspot if not enabled.
  You may save it as a `.ps1 file` and add it to the
  [Task Scheduler](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler)
  so it runs every minute or so.
- Alternatively, you can use [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/1468845/99602) instead, which is a small app that resides in the taskbar tray area.
  [image]

Comment: The first four steps are those I have already found on the internet and tried, so I guess the script is the only way to keep it on, I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Anyway, do you have any idea how the "turn on remotely" feature works?

Comment: It uses the [NetworkOperatorTetheringManager class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.networkoperatortetheringmanager) which controls and configures the mobile hotspot.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Oh yes, but I need to see at monday, when I get back to the computer with the hotspot on.

Comment: So, what I have used ultimately is an answer I found in the link you provided, it does the same thing the script does but is a dedicated app which resides in the taskbar tray area. https://superuser.com/a/1468845/99602